# css horizontally center select menu and label

Tags: css

I have a jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/z0yjvksg/38/

Super simple but its driving me mad.

I just need to center the select menu and label (red box) in the container (green box).

I've tried everything I can think of without actually adding padding or margins to push the box across.

```
    .form{
        border: 1px solid green;
        padding: 10px 0;
    }

    .search-form__by{
        border: 1px solid red;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        //text-align: center:

        label{
            float: left;
            margin: 7px 10px 0 0;
        }

        select{
            width: 200px;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add text-align to form class.

```
.form{
    border: 1px solid green;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Full solution:
https://jsfiddle.net/hs0bxyny/

Answer (score 2):

Add:

```
.row {
  text-align:center;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/z0yjvksg/41/)**

Or if you're using Bootstrap, add the class `text-center` to the row div: `<div class="row text-center">`

Comment: I have other things inside of row in the actual code that will also be centered

Comment: Are you saying that this doesn't work for you? It works based on the example code you provided. If you have other elements that could affect the outcome you should revise your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: It works but it centres everything in the row, I don't want everything centered

Comment: Then you need to modify your question because the code in it only has the label and select.